# Odoo Salesperson Orders restrict

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-12

i want that the salesperson only will see the order he created not every order i want to limit that to the record he created

'''

```
<record model="ir.module.category" id="module_category_flexipharmacy">
        <field name="name">Flexipharmacy</field>
        <field name="description">Select if salesperson or owner.</field>

    </record>

    <record id="group_flexipharmacy_salesperson" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Salesperson</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_flexipharmacy"/>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.rule" id="salesperson_view">
        <field name="name">Salesperson own order</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_pos_order"/>
        <field name="domain_force">[('user_id', '=', 'user.id')]</field>
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_flexipharmacy_salesperson'))]"/>
    </record>
```

'''

now after doing this i am not getting any record in my pos orders all are hidden

this is the "user_id" which is in the python part:-

`user_id = fields.Many2one( comodel_name='res.users', string='Salesperson', help="Person who uses the cash register. It can be a reliever, a student or an interim employee.", default=lambda self: self.env.uid, states={'done': [('readonly', True)], 'invoiced': [('readonly', True)]}, )`

Comment: hardik patel bro you are right...  in <field name="domain_force">[('user_id', '=', 'user.id')]</field>
 user.id should have been without quotes in quotes its taking as string so i am not getting any records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="salesperson_view">
    <field name="name">Salesperson own order</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_pos_order"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('user_id', '=', user.id)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_flexipharmacy_salesperson'))]"/>
</record>
```

Comment: are you saying i have to pass a new field of create_uid..
i already have a field of salesperson which is the current user which is logged in

Comment: Please again a bit more as answer than code only. To answer the comment you could mention the field `create_uid` as one of Odoo's default fields on "normal" models and what's behind it.

Comment: create_uid field is available in all the odoo tables. it's store the user id who created the record.and I saw that in your code you passed the 'user.id' as string which is wrong in the rule. That's why all the orders are hidden.

Comment: hardik patel... can you please say me how should i write that to see the orders which is for that specified salesperson

Comment: Replace my code with your rule, and make sure Salesperson boolean is True for that user in the user form view.